Problematic integration of antd pagination with only next and previous buttons
There are some apis that return 'nextPageToken' and 'previousPageToken' to move from one page result to another instead of apis that return results based on 'limit' and 'pageNumber' parameters .
I am integrating an api in my React App that returns 'nextPageToken' when I first call the api and if I call the same api with an extra parameter 'nextPageToken' , I get results for the next page , this response contains 'nextPageToken' ( for getting results of next page ) and 'previousPageToken' ( for getting results of previous page ) .
I want AntD pagination component with only Next and Previous buttons .
I tried the following code .
    const onPaginationButtonClick = (pageToken) => {
        pageToken!==""&& dispatch(getData({pageToken:pageToken, maxResults: 5 }));
    }
    const itemRender = (_, type, originalElement) => {
    if (type === 'prev') {
      return <a onClick={()=>onPaginationButtonClick(prevPageToken)}><LeftOutlined />Previous</a>;
    }
    if (type === 'next') {
      return <a onClick={()=>onPaginationButtonClick(nextPageToken)}>Next<RightOutlined /></a>;
    }
    // return originalElement;
    };
    <Pagination
        pageSize={5}
        itemRender={itemRender} 
        total={
        data && data?.pageInfo?.totalResults
    }
    onChange={onPaginationChange} 
    />

Using this code , I am able to get a UI like below .

But I am facing a problem here , when my page loads the first time , I see this pagination component everything looks fine . 'Previous' button is disabled ( because I'm on first page ) and 'Next' button is enabled .
Then , I click on 'Next' button to get results for next page . When new page results are loaded , then also I see that 'Previous' button is disabled .
What am I doing wrong ?

I expected Next and Previous buttons to work normally .
